# Can't set image to fit whole div

Tags: html, css

I've wanted to create some header for my website, but I actually can't set background image properly. I'd like from my background image to fill whole header div, but it's actually doesn't even fit whole div. What should I do with it? (Please don't blame me about code quality :D)

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
      <link

 href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
   </head>
    <body>
     <div class = "headerContainer">
      <div class = "headerCol1"><h1>LoremIpsum</h1></div>
      <div class = "headerCol2"><h1>LoremIpsum</h1></div>
      <div style = "clear:both;"/>
      <div class = "headerCol3"><h1>LoremIpsum</h1></div>
      <div style = "clear:both"/>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
    body{
    background-color:#666766;
}

.headerContainer{

    height:100vh;
    border:solid 2px;
    background-image:url("https://i2.wp.com/oddshjelpen.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/350851-download-free-website-background-1920x1080-for-mobile-hd.jpg?ssl=1");
    background-size: contain;
  background-position: left-top;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;

}
.headerCol1{
    height:100px;
    width:600px;
    background-color:yellow;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.headerCol1 h1{
    text-align:center;
    font-size:40px;
    padding:15px;

    font-size:72px;
    letter-spacing:15px;

}

.headerCol2{
    height:70px;
    width:500px;
    background-color:yellow;
    margin-top:150px;
    float:right;
}

.headerCol2 h1{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
    font-size:62px;

}

.headerCol3{
    height:65px;
    width:550px;
    background-color:yellow;
    margin-top:20px;
    float:right;
}
.headerCol3 h1{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
    font-size:56px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/48t7xLrg/

Comment: Is your `headerContainer` going to be `100vh`?

Comment: Just modify these properties `background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to update `background-size` to `cover` Update below css.

```
.headerContainer {
    height: 100vh;
    border: solid 2px;
    background-image: url(https://i2.wp.com/oddshjelpen.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/350851-download-free-website-background-1920x1080-for-mobile-hd.jpg?ssl=1);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: left-top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7s5g6eaj/1/)

Answer (score 0):

`contain` fills up one dimension (full width or full height) while `cover` fills the image up until both dimensions are touching the sides.

Also, don't have a fixed height value, because on smaller screens, your child elements will go outside the header. Replace `height` with `min-height`.

```
.headerContainer{
  /* height:100vh; */
  min-height: 100vh;
  border:solid 2px;
  background-image:url("https://i2.wp.com/oddshjelpen.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/350851-download-free-website-background-1920x1080-for-mobile-hd.jpg?ssl=1");
  /* background-size: contain; */
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: left-top;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```